# iPad Remote app with Apple TV 2 not remembering where I was in iTunes pane

Tags: ipad, appletv

Whenever I closed my smart cover or otherwise dismiss the Remote app, attempts to reopen the app result in a "reset", acting as though it was the first time remote was opened and "forgetting" where I was in the virtual iTunes view. The track playing shows on top of the iTunes view, but my track/album pane is cleared, and it is asking me what I want to connect to, just like when you first open the app.

Apple TV 2, iPad 2 with latest iOS

Answer (score 1):

My "Remote" app experience is somewhat similar, although I am usually connecting to iTunes on my Mac, not ATV.  There used to be a "Stay Connected" option in the app that's no longer there.  I too would love to find a way to "stay connected", so I can just jump back into Remote to see what's playing!